# Redirect script output both to console and to log

Tags: linux, shell-script, logs, io-redirection, tee

Take a look on the following

```
# more  /tmp/myscript
#!/bin/bash


echo I AM
echo BIG GUY
echo AND ALSO SMART

# bash   /tmp/myscript | tee -a >/tmp/log
```

why we not get the output from echo in the script to the console?

**actually output redirect to the log - /tmp/log**
*but not also to the standard output*

its very strange because tee -a should redirect top log and also to stand art output

**what is the right way to write to log and print to console ?**

expected output

```
# bash   /tmp/myscript | tee -a >/tmp/log

     I AM
     BIG GUY
     AND ALSO SMART
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's because you use the redirection of output `>`. `tee` should do the redirection, not the shell. Try without `>`:

```
bash /tmp/myscript | tee -a /tmp/log
```